# BufferedInputStream read vs IOUtils toByteArray

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream

I recently tried reading data from inputStream.

```
int length = getHeader("Content-Length");
byte[] buffer = new byte [length];    
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream (servletRequest.getInputStream());    
stream.read(buffer);
```

It was truncating my data somehow. When I tried following

```
buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(servletRequest.getInputStream());
```

It worked perfectly.

Can anybody give me insights on what could be the issue ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What if the content length is not accurate?

Comment: Two things. First, what does your `getHeader` do? Is it returning the right value? Second, `read(byte[])` returns an `int` value showing how many bytes were actually read into the buffer. If that's not what you expected, you need to loop, calling that method (or its overload with an offset) until you've read everything. That's more or less what `toByteArray` does.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, likely the problem.

Comment: you can wrap the stream in DataInputStream and then use readFully() which will do all the looping until the whole byte array is filled with data. but as tim points out, with HTTP the content length could be wrong, or more commonly, missing (it's not mandatory). In which case the IOUtils method is safer

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Consider it pseudo code. It is getting the required header from the request. Also, Content length is accurate, it matches exactly what is being sent.

Comment: So your problem is exactly as described. There is nothing in the contract of `BufferedInputStream.read()` that says it will fill the buffer. You have to loop, or use `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: @EJP [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read(byte[]) ) says that it will call read (buffer, 0, length) internally. This calls read() repeatedly length times. What am I missing ?

Comment: @GauravJoshi If the underlying InputStream.available() returned 0, it will return too. This is the difference between BufferredInputStream.read() and DataInputStream.readFully().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gaurav_Joshi

The BufferedInputStream constructor that takes one argument InputStream uses DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, which could be less than the actual size of your input stream.

```
public BufferedInputStream(InputStream in) {
    this(in, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly my issue ! My data length is quite big, which might be bigger than DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE ! Awesome ! Thanks !

Comment: I believe this answer didn't answer the question.